# How to have an incremntal column along with fixed one in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I want to have an array like this:
second column with values from 1 to 1000.
first column with zero value for first 1000 ones, one for second 1000 values,... till 1000.

```
[ 0 1
  0 2
  ...
  0 1000
  1 1
  1 2
  ...
  1 1000
  1000 1
  1000 2
  ...
  1000 1000]
```

What I've tried would not increment the values of first column.

```
 z = ones (10000, 2);
    for i=1:1000
        z(:,2)= (1:1:1000);
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a smart way :), with no loop.

Try:

```
firstColumn = repmat(0:1000,1000,1);
firstColumn = firstColumn(:); % Convert to a single column vector
secondColumn = repmat([1:1000]', 1001, 1); 
M = [firstColumn secondColumn];
```

Read [repmat](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [column, :](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html?s_tid=doc_ta) if you are  struggling to understand the code above.